# !! Unexpected error while processing request: failed to allocate memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Please help me in solving this error.

I am getting this error while loading records from text files in to database using ruby scripts.

It just works fine if I use small number of records to load in to the database.But fails if there are large number of records.

```
CSV.foreach(fileName) do |line|
    completePath = line[0]                                                
    num_of_bps = line[1]

    completePath = cluster_path+ '/' + completePath
    inode = FileOrFolder.find_by_fullpath(completePath, :select=>"id") 

    metric_instance = MetricInstance.find(:first, :conditions=>["file_or_folder_id = ? AND dataset_id = ?", inode.id, dataset_id])
    add_entry(metric_instance.id, num_of_bps, num_of_bp_tests) 
end

def self.add_entry(metaid, num_of_bps, num_of_bp_tests)
    entry = Bp.new
    entry.metric_instance_id = metaid
    entry.num_of_bps = num_of_bps
    entry.num_of_bp_tests = num_of_bp_tests
    entry.save
    return entry
end
```

Comment: You'll need to narrow this down to a reasonable size sample script that exhibits the error and show your script in your question. Otherwise, there's just not enough information here for anyone to help.

Comment: I have added the script code please review it.... there are several files in the same fashion that are being loaded in to database.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
File.open(fileName) do |csv|
  csv.each_line do |line|
    CSV.parse(line) do |values|
      # Here you can do your manipulation
    end
  end
end
```

This way is slower, but it should ensure you don't get out of memory.

Comment: Thanks ! ... is the out-of-memory issue specific to the file size ? if so is there any way in ruby to check the file size within the script and call appropriate method? and also where can we check the maximum allowed size of the file?

Comment: You have size method of File class: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html. You can also check available physical memory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029391/how-do-you-find-the-physical-memory-free-on-the-machine-in-ruby. Maximum memory that x86 programs can allocate is 2^32B=4GB and this can be a problem if you are using 32 bit Ruby. And the memory allocated in this case primarily depends of the file size (because it is a big file), and some memory is also used by the other variables on the heap.

Comment: @Ermin......Could you please answer this question ..... [link_to_question_2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149761/failed-to-allocate-memory-on-the-console-and-internal-server-error-on-the-browse)

Comment: @Ermin...could you please answer my question at ..... [link_question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218324/is-there-an-efficient-way-than-csv-foreach-way-of-reading-files)